Why has the intern method changed in different versions?
String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");
s1.intern();
String s2 = "11";
System.out.println(s1 == s2);//jdk6:false;jdk7:true;jdk8:true;jdk17:false

The same code above is false in jdk6, but true in jdk7 and jdk8, and false in jdk17. Why is this?
I want to know what changes have occurred here

You are not using the return value of intern(), is that intentional?

Cause of this may not be related to changes in intern method. Maybe simply Java at those versions used "11" somewhere internally, which would add "11" to String pool earlier, before executing your code (like when String class needs to be loaded to handle String in main(String[] args)). Try to test using other strings like String s1 = new String("1a2b") + new String("3c4d"); and String s2 = "1a2b3c4d";.

@Progman Value of s1.intern() should be in s2 since we assigned "11" literal to it directly, so it should come from String pool.

@Pshemo s1.intern() does not "replace" the string instance currently referencing by s1 or makes this string as the "intern" one. There might already be an interned string "11" in the pool. There is no guarantee that the string referencing s1 is the same as the already interned string literal "11", which is referenced by s2. So s1 == s2 might be false. But s1.intern() == s2 should (IIRC) definitely be true.

Please [edit] your question to include the exact java compiler version you are using and the exact java runtime version you are using to run your application. Also, if possible, add the output of javap of the generated .class files (for the java versions you are using).

@Progman "s1.intern() does not "replace" the string instance currently referencing by s1 or makes this string as the "intern" one" true, I never claimed otherwise. My point is that when we write String s2 = "11"; the s2 will hold same reference which was returrned by s1.intern(). So while OP is "not using the return value of intern()" directly/explicitly the s2 will hold that result anyway (since string literals come from String pool), so OP is using result of s1.intern() implicitly via s2 variable.

related intern() behaving differently in Java 6 and Java 7 but is not the only reason, as Pshemo wrote, " 11" can already be in the String pool as probably is the case with Java 17 (test System.out.println(s1 == s1.intern());)

String.intern() behaves as specified.
From the JavaDoc of Java 1.0.2

Creates a canonical representation for the string object.
If s and t are strings such that s.equals(t), it is guaranteed that
s.intern() == t.intern()
Returns:
a string that has the same contents as this string, but is guaranteed to be from a pool of unique strings.

to the JavaDoc of Java 22:

Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.
It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.
All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the The Java Language Specification.
Returns:
a string that has the same contents as this string, but is guaranteed to be from a pool of unique strings.

it never guarantees that for a randomly constructed string s1 == s1.intern() will return true.
Especially in some Java versions (probably starting from 1.1 up to Java 1.6) the interned strings are maintained in a special memory segment called the PermGen space. Randomly generated strings are stored in the normal heap, and calling String.intern() on a string that is stored in the heap will return another string (containing the same sequence of characters) that resides in the PermGen space. This is handled in the symbolTable.cpp source file

Citations please.
